# PDF signing with PDFBox using save method instead of saveIncremental

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I wonder if it's possible to sign a PDF with Pdfbox using the save method instead of saveIncremental. I would like to add a signature to the PDF without creating an increment. If I add a PDSignature to the PDDocument then I can see the Contents and the ByteRange tags in the source but the ByteRange will be [0 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000] which does not seem to be correct and the Contents contains only zeros. I know that the SignatureInterface is not called when I use the save method so I wonder if there is any other way to achieve this kind of signing?

Comment: You can *prepare* a PDF for signing using `save` but then you still have to do some coding for which you should know what you're doing. PDFBox only for `saveIncremental` provides an explicit signing API which can be used without knowing that much about PDF signing.

Comment: This would be possible only for the first signature. Starting from the 2nd everything has be be in the incremental update mode...

Comment: @Lonzak That's my goal. I only want the first signature this way. Not sure if any other signature is needed though.

Comment: In theory you could save this and leave placeholders (signature and ranges), then find these placeholders and get the "all-except-signature" content and sign it. CreateSignatureBase can be used without PDFBox, you just pass the inputstream and get a bytes array. What needs to be done is some non-PDF programming to overwrite at the correct positions. I think it's an interesting idea.

Comment: Yes, non-PDF programming was kind of my backup plan. I was looking at PDFBox classes first like COSDocument and COSWriter if I could find a way to reuse those classes and adapt them to this kind of signing. Now I try to fix the non-PDF way to see if it will work at all. I add a signature so I have the placeholders with the ByteRange and Contents then I try to change the ByteRange and extract the bytes which needs to be signed and then change the Contents to the real signature.